# big query python API insert null values through json

Tags: python, json, null, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have a big query table with 4 columns : name (string) , age(int) , score(float) , dob (datetime).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

from google.cloud import bigquery


def stream_data(json_data):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client("myproject")
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset("ComputedData")
    table = dataset.table("test")
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    table.reload()
    rows = [data]
    errors = table.insert_data(rows)

    if not errors:
        print('Loaded 1 row ')
    else:
        print('Errors: {}'.format(errors))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mynam = 'mike'
    mage = 212
    mydob='1983-09-01 00:00:00'
    mydob=None
    ds=str(mydob) if mydob else None
    myscore = 0;
    stream_data('["' + str(mynam) + '",' + str(mage) + ',"' + ds + '",'+ str(myscore) +']')
```

The above is  a sample to test whether I can insert null values . For eg. I actually compute the score and date of birth (assume) and insert it. But if the computation does not work I want to insert null into the big query table as datetime supports null.

By default , null is None in python. However I cannot insert this into the as I cannot concat Nonetype as string . 
 If I try to stringify the null statement as :

```
 ds=str(mydob) if mydob else 'null'
```

I get 'Invalid datetime string "null"'

I am not sure if I am generating my json the wrong way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlI2.png)

I do get nulls but for that I have to leave out the field in the json.

```
   stream_data('["' + str(mynam) + '",' + str(mage) + ']')
```

I cannot do this as if I want to enter score but leave dob as null , if I insert

```
stream_data('["' + str(mynam) + '",' + str(mage) + ',' + str(myscore)+']')
```

This inserts or tries to insert score in the datetime column. So I have to insert a value for every column in the json. but want to be able to specify nulls while inserting.

Comment: Try to not insert anything rather than Null or non or 'null'; Like this:
`name,12,,123` (not the two commas).
Ideally BQ should default to the default date. 
If it does not, some alternatives:
   - push the default date yourself (1970)
   - put the field as string, and write null instead (depends what you do with the date afterwards).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the problem here is that the `insert_data` method works with a list of tuples and not json.

I just created a table like yours in BQ and used the same code as yours but instead of converting to json I used the function as it's described in the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.insert_data), like so:

```
error = table.insert_data([('name1', 200, None, '1990-09-09 00:00:00'),
                           ('name2', 201, 67.3,)])
```

Among the tests I did I also tried:

```
error = table.insert_data([('name3', 301, 35.4,None)])
```

And also:

```
error = table.insert_data([(None, None, None,None)])
```

It all worked:

[image]

Maybe what you can do is (if your code receives for some reason the json) to first transform this json into a list of tuples and then send this list to the `insert_data` method with `NULL` values as `None`.